# Traduction d'une phrase comportant le mot « referees »

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

Je voudrais savoir comment dire en français cette phrase :

> Send us a short statement of your interests, your CV, and the contact addresses of two referees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voici une traduction possible de la phrase:

> Envoyez-nous une courte liste de vos centres d'intérêt, votre CV et
>   l'adresse de contact de deux de vos références.

ici **références** sont des personnes qui pourront appuyer ta candidature, par exemple des anciens patrons/maîtres de stage

Comment: Merci ! J'avais réfléchi au mot << référence >> mais je voulais une vérification :-)! Au fait, la traduction de cette phrase donnée par un service en ligne très populaire était un peu de catastrophe ayant interprété referees par arbitres...Du coup, je suis content d'avoir trouvé french.stack.exchange !